# Line break in InnerText, no chance to use InnerHtml

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am displaying XML source code in web page..

My code is

```
<div id="esdcatalogXml" runat="server"></div>
```

and C# is:

```
string xmlSource = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Value"].ToString()) ;
esdcatalogXml.InnerText = xmlSource;
```

I want to show line by line in my webpage.. But getting all lines in a single line.

Please help

Comment: I'd suggest using the `pre` element instead of a `div` for this.

Comment: I would prefer what James suggested use it something like <pre id="esdcatalogXml" runat="server"></pre>

Comment: What does `"Value"` look like? Can you include an excerpt?

Comment: Thank you very much James.. \n is working in <pre> tag, My issue is fixed.